# Как очистить/удалить файлы из истории git?

Tags: git, bitbucket

После введения новой политики о безопасности в компании, попросили очистить из коммитов список файлов (файлы могут хранится локально, но не быть доступными через git BitBucket).

Как "очистить" все следы о содержимом файлов из git репозитория?

Comment: Если только удалить весь репозиторий с BitBucket. Интересно только, как вы в этой ситуации будете обмениваться изменениями. Разве что запустите собственный Git-сервер внутри сети компании?..

Comment: А-а. Стоп. Под "список файлов" имелось в виду "некоторые из файлов в репозитории"? В этом случае нет, репозторий удалять не надо, конечно. Это, потенциально, полное переписывание истории через какой-нибудь `filter-branch`, и подобные вопросы тут уже 100%-но поднимались.

Comment: @D-side так и было, залил на Atlssian публичный теперь нужно чистить.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно удалить файл из удаленного репозитория воспользуйтесь командой

```
git rm --cached mylogfile.log
```

Для удаления директории из удаленного репозитория

```
git rm --cached -r mydirectory
```

После этого закоммитьте и запушьте изменения в репозиторий. В локальном репозитории файлы если они есть останутся, а из удаленного удалятся.

Comment: кто-то говорил, что репозиторий удалён? Он есть, он там. Нужно только избавиться от некоторых, возможно довольно древних комитов с секретными файлами

Comment: Удалённый репозитория -  это не располоденный локально, а на каком-то сервере.

Comment: О, теперь понял. Ваш ответ всё равно не то, что нужно автору. Он хочет удалить все действия связанный с конкретным файлом. Возможно, что файл был добавлен очень давно и изменялся каждый день.

Comment: @LEQADA нужно очистить репозиторий на BitBucket компании, оставив не тронутыми сами файлы на сервере, который в офисе.

Comment: Это вы так только из нового коммита удалите. Считайте, бумажкой прикрыли только, а не удалили. Кому нужно, всегда сможет посмотреть в ранние коммиты и найти там засекреченные файлы.

Answer (score 0):

git bash

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-status | grep -i ^D | cut -f2- | sort -u | xargs -I {} git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch {}' HEAD
```

Просто вычеркнет все удаленные файлы из коммитов. Потребуется прилично времени на выполнение, если коммитов очень много. Если хочешь оптимизировать команду, то дерзай.

Comment: BFG попроще будет :) https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/