# Удалить файл из коммита (старого)

Tags: python, git, github, git-commit, git-push

В один из коммитов попал файл архива размером 172Mb, так что github не позволяет сделать push,(да и не нужно пушить этот архив).
При попытке сделать push из любого коммита, находящегося выше коммита,где появился архив, github почему-то пушит и сам архив.

Comment: Нужно откатиться до коммита с файлом, убрать его и накатить изменения заново

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1098465/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-git-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8

Comment: @eri, для этого есть _git rebase --interactive ..._.

Comment: дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/975036/178576) [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/426401/178576) [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/778992/178576) [4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/669670/178576) и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin нет, не помогло

Comment: @ГерманБорисов нет, не помогло, при пуше git все равно загружает этот архив

Comment: значит, возможно, этот файл [упомянут в других ветках](https://stackoverflow.com/a/372970/4827341).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасио, помогло.

Comment: Чтобы файл совсем удалить из гита: 
`git filter-branch --force --index-filter \ 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch <archive_name>' \ --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`

Answer (score 1):

`git rm --cached <archive_name>`

Затем запушить и добавить архив в `.gitignore`

Comment: Добавление в `.gitignore` лишь вопрос удобства.
А вот в гите файл всё равно останется, если он уже попал в коммит.